# How to detect a cycle in a undirected graph?

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search

Good morning, currently I am stuck on trying to figure out how to detect a cycle in a undirected graph where the keys are strings.

my code so far:

```
public boolean hascycle() {
    DSHashMap<String> parent = new DSHashMap<>();
    DSHashMap<String> visted = new DSHashMap<>();
    LinkedList<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
    for (String start : graph) {
      q.add(start);
      visted.put(start, "");
      ;
      while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        String v = q.poll();
        for (String x : graph.get(v)) {
          if (!visted.containsKey(x)) {
            visted.put(x, "");
            ;
            q.add(v);
            parent.put(x, v);
          } else if (!parent.get(x).equals(v))
            return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

My logic so far: if the key of parent does not equal to v, it must be a new neighbor and we should return true.

When I tried checking my code with this checker:

```
private static void gradehascycles() {
    System.out.println("\nGrading the cycles function");
        DSGraph g = new DSGraph();
        g.addEdge("a", "b");
        g.addEdge("a", "e");
        g.addEdge("c", "b");
        g.addEdge("c", "d");
        checkExpect(g.hascycle(), false, "Square graph", 1);
}
```

My code returned true even though it was supposed to be false. What is the logic behind checking if a graph has a cycle or not?

Comment: Can you post your entire class so that it was possible to debug it?

Comment: Sure, here I will post the github link: https://github.com/RoyBoy189/ADSHomework

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? It returns true when it checks neighbors of a, in particular e. It does so because at this moment a parent of a is b, not e.
What I think you should do, is at each iteration of for loop for (String start : graph)  you should check if the start is visited and not proceed if it is.

Comment: Overall, your algorithm seems to be correct, at least I saw that there working solutions on the geekforgeeks that work in a similar way. Although it's considered a preferred way to use DFS for checking for acyclicity. Anyway, it doesn't make much sense to visit an already visited connected component which you do at the moment at each iteration of your for loop. P.S. I'm not really that good with graphs to help you more.

Comment: Yea I figured it out and it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two classic ways of finding cycles in graphs: one is by using DFS (depth first search) algorithm and label the edges and look for [back edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search).

And the other one is to use the union-find algorithm (aka Disjoint Set data structure) which is used in many applications for cycle detection, especially when you have an undirected graph.

###### Here's a few useful links about DFS and union-find algorithms for graph cycle detection to get you started:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find/

Note: There are other ways you can detect cycles in graphs, but they are usually not as efficient as the ones mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
else if (!parent.get(v).equals(x))
            return true;
        }
```

Explanation:
[image]
Let's say that you started traversing a graph with A, you marked it as visited (I highlighted it with yellow), and then started traversing its neighbors, B, E. You marked them as visited as well and updated their parent reference to point to A, you also added them to the q. Then you extract the next element from the q,  let's say it was B. According to your naming B is v, and its neighbors A and C are x's. You inspect A first. It's already been visited so you proceed to
else if clause and check that parent of x (A) is v (B). But it's not, A doesn't have a parent, you compare null with v, and it's not equal, so your code returns true.

Comment: When I used ```else if (!parent.get(v).equals(x))
            return true;
        }``` I get a error exception. Key no found:  a